# Don't understand jquery - setting equal height contained divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set two side-by-side divs contained by a single larger div to equal column height.  I am trying to use the following jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function pageLoad() {           
            $(document).ready(function() {
                setEqualHeight($(".instructionsParent > div"));
            });    
        }

        function setEqualHeight(columns) {
            var tallestColumn = 0;

            columns.each(function() {
                currentHeight = $(this).height();
                if(currentHeight > tallestColumn) {
                    tallestColumn = currentHeight;
                }
            });
            columns.height(tallestColumn);
        }
</script>
```

Then the following are my DIV's:

```
<div class="instructionsParent borderDiv borderTable0" style="overflow:hidden">
    <div class="instructionsLeft" style="float:left;width:49.5%">
  </div>    
  <div class="instructionsRight" style="float:right;width:49.5%">
  </div>
</div>
```

The jquery is running and appears to be returning the largest height (451), but doesn't seem to apply it to the two divs.  I don't know much jquery or javascript and don't understand the following: "setEqualHeight($(".instructionsParent > div"));"

Could it be that I have that coded incorrectly?

Thank you,
James

Ok, here is the entire subform which is my entire page really (I have two subforms on the page with one visible and the other not:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ActivexInstructionsSubForm.ascx.vb" Inherits="Controls_ActivexInstructionsSubForm" %>

<div class="instructionsParent borderDiv borderTable0" style="overflow:hidden">
<div class="instructionsLeft" style="float:left;width:49.5%">
    <table cellspacing="0" class="borderTable0" width="100%" style="height:430px;" >
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <br />
                <h3 style="font-family:Arial;color:#17238C">"The Important Stuff"</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td align="center">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" 
                    style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;color:#17238C">
                                        <p style="font-size:11pt"><strong style="text-decoration: underline;font-size:11pt;font-style:normal">If this is the first time</strong> you've used our downloads, you now can see a
                                            skinny information bar at the top of the page.&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            Click it, and select "Install ActiveX Control" from the dropdown menu.&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            Then, click "Install" when you see the new dialog box appear.&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            This does not collect info about you or hurt your machine.
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            //Create JavaScript object that will embed File Downloader to the page
                                            var fd = new FileDownloaderWriter("FileDownloader", 172, 28);

                                            //For ActiveX control full path to CAB file (including file name) should be specified
                                            fd.activeXControlCodeBase = "aurigma/FileDownloader2.cab";
                                            fd.activeXControlVersion = "2,0,16,0";

                                            //Set the Download button text
                                            fd.addParam("ButtonDownloadText", "Proceed With Download");

                                            //Set the Download button background color
                                            //fd.addParam("BackgroundColor", "#E0EBFF");
                                            fd.addParam("BackgroundColor", "White");

                                            //Set the Download button regular image
                                            fd.addParam("ButtonDownloadImageFormat", "width=172;height=28;BackgroundColor=#17238C;" + 
                                                "urlNormal=App_Themes/Default/images/BtnProceedDownloadA.jpg;" +
                                                "urlDisabled=App_Themes/Default/images/BtnProceedDownloadA.jpg");

                                            //Set license key 
                                            fd.addParam("LicenseKey", "888822-12222-D8444-111122-55555");

                                            //Set reconnect attampts count
                                            fd.addParam("ReconnectAttemptsCount", "360");

                                            //Set reconnect timeout value (30000 = 10 seconds)
                                            fd.addParam("ReconnectTimeOut", "10000");

                                            //Configure URL from which the file list will be downloaded
                                            //Change this path if necessary
                                            //fd.addParam("FileList", "aurigma/filelist.txt");

                                            //The following listener will perform some actions when the file list is about to be downloaded
                                            fd.addEventListener("DownloadStep", "FileDownloader_DownloadStep");

                                            //The following listener will perform some actions when download of a single file is finished
                                            fd.addEventListener("DownloadItemComplete", "onDownloadItemComplete");

                                            //The following listener will perform some actions when download process is complete
                                            fd.addEventListener("DownloadComplete", "onDownloadComplete");

                                            //The following listener will perform some actions when a general error is detected
                                            //fd.addEventListener("Error", "onError");

                                            //Add page load listener
                                            //fd.fullPageLoadListenerName = "fullPageLoad";

                                            //Set instructions property
                                            fd.instructionsEnabled = false;

                                            //Tell File Downloader writer object to generate all necessary HTML code to embed File Downloader into the page
                                            fd.writeHtml();
                                        </script>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnReturnHome" runat="server" AlternateText="Return to Home Page" 
                                            ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/BtnReturnHomeS.jpg">
                                        </asp:ImageButton> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-weight:normal;font-style:italic;color:#17238C">
                                        <p style="font-size:10pt"><strong style="text-decoration: underline;font-size:11pt;font-style:normal">Why do I need this?</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>  
                                            This tiny control-program is only installed ONCE on a given machine,
                                            and is there to assist with all future downloads.&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            It allows you to download a batch of several files at once, save
                                            them wherever you wish, AND keeps track of the download progress.&nbsp;&nbsp;If your internet connection glitches, the
                                            download will *automatically restart* (after a couple of minutes) 
                                            from where it left off, once the internet connection is restored, presuming that your computer remains powered on.&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            This is a very important feature, since these are BIG files that may take
                                            several hours to download if you have a relatively slow internet connection.</strong> 
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr> 
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="instructionsRight" style="float:right;width:49.5%">
    <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="borderTable0" style="height:430px;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <br style="height:20px" />
                <h4 style="color:#17238C">Additional Info</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td align="center">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" 
                    style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;color:#17238C">
                                        <p style="font-size:9pt"><strong style="text-decoration: underline;font-size:11pt;font-style:normal">Worst-case scenario</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>
                                            If the transfer fails because your computer shut down from a power-outage, there may be a temporary file left on your
                                            machine - but the next time you start the download, it automatically cleans up what was left from the aborted transfer.&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            If you tend to get hit by electric power outages more often than normal, we recommend that you purchase a battery-backup UPS
                                            (Uninterruptible Power Supply) that has at least 1500VA capacity so that the computer AND your modem AND router can remain
                                            powered-up for several hours when the power goes out.&nbsp;&nbsp;Start the download before going to bed, and TURN OFF the monitor
                                            during that process, so that the UPS would not have to feed it if a power outage hits.</strong>
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;color:#17238C">
                                        <p style="font-size:9pt"><strong style="text-decoration: underline;font-size:11pt;font-style:normal">Gotta-shut-down scenario</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>
                                            If you are in the midst of a long download session, but for some reason you must interrupt it and turn off your computer
                                            a while, then if you want to resume the download from where you left off, be sure to HIBERNATE your machine rather than
                                            doing a simple shutdown.  You can set this up from Control Panel > Power Options > Hibernate Tab.  There will be a button
                                            on your keyboard somewhere that activates hibernation (sometimes called "sleep").  It takes a complete "RAM snapshot" of
                                            what is going on, so that the next time you start the computer, it resumes exactly where it left off (it may take a few
                                            minutes after restart for the download to auto-resume).</strong>
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="height:24px">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the pageLoad() function (I don't think you were calling it).

See :
http://paulisageek.com/tmp/jquery/equal_height.html

Comment: I got Object expected jscript error if I remove pageLoad.  The query does run and returns a good value but isn't applying it to the divs.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  Yes your example works fine.  Let me check a couple things first.  

Thanks, Jim

Comment: Ok, removed the pageLoad and it runs without the error, but still doesn't set the divs to equal height.  I posted the entire subform.

Comment: Are you including jquery and the javascript correctly? works for me : http://paulisageek.com/tmp/jquery/equal_height2.html

Comment: I use:
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.1.js" language="javascript">

Do I need more?

Comment: Also, this is on the login page, so I have to allow all users to access any files in the web.config file under forms authentication. I have done so for the jquery file.  Is there a file for javascript somewhere that would need access?  I don't think it would run if that were the case.

Comment: Install firebug into firefox, and then view your page and make sure nothing under the Net tab is red. And make sure there are no console errors too.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  Thank you Paul

Comment: Well I installed Firefox and Firebug...  Pretty cool stuff.  Initially I had one red error in the NET tab accessing a file but I have corrected that.  Nothing in console.  I will play with Firebug a bit more to see if I can determine more.  This whole thing is very odd.  Thanks

Comment: What I have found is that it IS setting the height of the container which contains the two divs I intended to set.  Why is my script setting the container height rather than it's children?

Comment: Clarification: It IS setting the height of my instructionsParent div, not the instructionsLeft and instructionsRight divs.

Comment: There is no div inbetween? `".instructionsParent > div"` means the immediate child div of anything with the class instructionsParent

Comment: I got it fixed.  I had some other things including tables under the divs.  It works great now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the pageload function worked for me. The script on my working page reads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
       setEqualHeight($(".instructionsParent > div"));
    });    


    function setEqualHeight(columns) {
        console.log("here")

        var tallestColumn = 0;

        columns.each(function() {
            currentHeight = $(this).height();
            if(currentHeight > tallestColumn) {
                tallestColumn = currentHeight;
            }
        });
        columns.height(tallestColumn);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Note: I tested this in three different scenarios:

1) one column having text coded directly in the div but no style setting for height
2) one div having text but a style setting for height
3) no text or style setting for height, but jQuery generated text on document load, before calling the setEqualHeights function

Worked in all 3 cases.