# Javascript not working as expected, why?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have javascript to set equal column heights of two divs contained by a parent div.  Somebody even coded an working example that works (mine doesn't).  What I have found is that it IS setting the height of the container which contains the two divs I intended to set.  Why is my script setting the container height rather than it's children?  Please see my previous question at:

[Don't understand jquery - setting equal height contained divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458233/dont-understand-jquery-setting-equal-height-contained-divs)

What does the following line actually do?  I don't understand the "> div" part.

setEqualHeight($(".instructionsParent > div"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parent > child
```

"Matches all child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent"."

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child#parentchild

Answer (score 0):

The selector ".instructionsParent > div" means "select all the div elements that are children under the element with the class instructionsParent".  So the div elements are the elements selected here.